# Is there a way to squash commits in fork after pull request was accepted to original repo?

Tags: git, pull-request, git-fork

I have a fork of repository where I'm writing my parts of code. I made quite a mistake of writing pieces of code (usually it's a kind of ~50-100 lines of sql code) into master branch of fork (I didn't realise it at the time though) and then pull requesting master branch of fork into master branch of origin.

Settings in original repo allow me only to squash and merge commits. So right now I'm in the situation where every pull request is like 60 commits and 1 file changed (the actual I worked on).

Is there a way to somehow sync states of original repo and fork, to remove all unnecessary commits from master branch?

Comment: You are looking for a `rebase`

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer**

First, use `fetch` in your `fork` to acquire *information* about the state of `origin` (the original repo)

Then, you'll be able to compare their states and decide what you want to do.

You'll be able to rewrite the history of your `fork` to match `origin`
It will more difficult to make changes to `origin` to match your `fork` though:

- You'll need push authority on `origin` to rewrite history
- If you don't have it, you'll need to coordinate with someone who can do it for you
- Since `origin` is shared amongst other people, they'll need to be notified because it may interrupt things they're working on

For a more detailed answer on what operations may help you achieve this, you'll need to provide more specifics about the current state of `origin` and your `fork`, and what state you intend for them. This command may help:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I managed to find workable solution:

- Find a commit hash before your first commit
- git reset --hard
- git push -f origin master
- git pull upstream master
- git push origin master

And my fork (origin here) is synced with upstream.

Comment: By "your first commit" do you mean the first commit of the fork or the first commit of the latest work since the latest PR from the fork?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked through this problem, but if I"m not mistaken, it was a first commit of the fork